# How do I create a Batch file to change an exe installer to Win XP SP3 compatibility mode and launch installer

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

This is all I could get to. I also was trying to call this batch file from the source batch file. Don't ask my why I'm using the CD. That doesn't work but basically I'm trying to set the compatiblity mode for all EXE's in that directory. I am copying the files locally because I have not figured out how to run them from the server:

Here is: !Set_Comp_Mode.bat

```
cd "C:\Temp\Pivotal 6.0.12 HF2\5-Reinstall After Pivotal 6 - Pivotal 5.9r4\"
pause
for %x in ("*.exe") do reg.exe Add "HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\AppCompatFlags\Layers" /v "%~fx" /d "WINXPSP3"
```

I'm also trying to "Run As Admin" all I have to do is prompt for the credentials but maybe there is a better way?

Here is the mother batch:

```
@ECHO off
cls
:start
ECHO.
ECHO 1-PREREQ6.0.10
ECHO 2-PivotalPackagedClient6.0.12
ECHO 3-PackagedClientSP12_HotFix2
ECHO 4-ExeFolderFix
ECHO 5-Reinstall After Pivotal 6 - Pivotal 5.9r4
ECHO 6-Pivotal 5.9r5 HB NoC
ECHO 7-Exit
set /p choice=Menu:
rem if not '%choice%'=='' set choice=%choice:~0;1% ( don`t use this command, because it takes only first digit in the case you type more digits. After that for example choice 23455666 is choice 2 and you get "bye"
rem if not '%choice%'=='' ECHO "%choice%" is not valid please try again
if '%choice%'=='1' goto Step1
if '%choice%'=='2' goto Step2
if '%choice%'=='3' goto Step3
if '%choice%'=='4' goto Step4
if '%choice%'=='5' goto Step5
if '%choice%'=='6' goto Step6
if '%choice%'=='7' goto end
ECHO.
goto start

:Step1
ECHO ****1-PREREQ6.0.10****
runas /noprofile /savecred /user:Administrator "%~dp01-PREREQ6.0.10\setup.exe" 

goto start

:Step2
ECHO ****2-PivotalPackagedClient6.0.12****
runas /noprofile /savecred /user:Administrator "%~dp02-PivotalPackagedClient6.0.12\ManualInstall.bat"
goto start

:Step3
ECHO ****3-PackagedClientSP12_HotFix2****
runas /noprofile /savecred /user:Administrator "%~dp03-PackagedClientSP12_HotFix2\ManualInstall.bat"
goto start

:Step4
ECHO ****4-ExeFolderFix****
runas /noprofile /savecred /user:Administrator "%~dp04-ExeFolderFix\Copy_Fixed_EXE_Folder.bat"
goto start

:Step5
ECHO ****5-Reinstall After Pivotal 6 - Pivotal 5.9r4****
runas /noprofile /savecred /user:Administrator "%~dp0!Set_Comp_Mode.bat"
runas /noprofile /savecred /user:Administrator "%~dp05-Reinstall After Pivotal 6 - Pivotal 5.9r4\Pivotal_5.9r4_HB.EXE"
goto start

:Step6
ECHO ****6-Pivotal 5.9r5 HB NoC****
runas /noprofile /savecred /user:Administrator "%~dp06-Pivotal 5.9r5 HB NoC\Pivotal59r5HBNoC.bat"
goto end

:end
pause
exit
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: Read Title, I made edits

Answer (score 0):

Create a shortcut, set it's properties how you want, execute the shortcut. Shortcut's to programs have a always hidden extention of `lnk`. `pif` for MSDos programs and `url` for internet links.

For compatability options EXCEPT for Run As Admin (because there is no code to force elevation it will prevent some programs from running) try this

```
Set __Compat_Layer=WinXPSP3
```

See https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/286705#/en-us/kb/286705

Comment: I tried testing this in my batch without success. It is an EXE that I have copied to a c:\temp. I want to be able to loop through and apply this setting to any EXE in the directory. Maybe I'm doing it wrong. `for %x in ("*.exe") do Set __Compat_Layer=WinXPSP3` just doesn't look right.